# redis cluster different machines

Tags: configuration, redis, cluster-computing

I've setup a 6 node cluster using Redis version 3.0.501 (latest from MSOpenTech git repo) on 3 separate Windows machines.

All 6 redis.conf files are:

```
port 638x
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes
```

Each machine runs 2 nodes. Here's my abbreviated nodes.conf (id's are shortened for readability):

```
2a63e8 192.168.1.23:6380 myself,master - 0 0 10 connected 5461-10922
e1bfd8 192.168.1.29:6382 master - 0 1465205145106 16 connected 0-5460
0c4942 192.168.1.29:6381 slave 2a63e8 0 1465205145544 10 connected
a68197 192.168.1.22:6385 slave 05f029 0 1465205146966 13 connected
05f029 192.168.1.22:6384 master - 0 1465205146231 13 connected 10923-16383
604068 192.168.1.23:6383 slave e1bfd8 0 1465205145435 16 connected
vars currentEpoch 16 lastVoteEpoch 16
```

Here you see the two nodes, 6385 a slave of 6384, on 192.168.1.22. If that machine dies, is that not a single point of failure? How do I prevent one of the machines to have a slave node connected to a master on the same machine?

Answer (score 3):

Set up the cluster manually to configure the slave that each master uses. Follow the [tutorial](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial#creating-and-using-a-redis-cluster) from the redis website to learn how to manually create a cluster.

I would create the cluster with masters only from the start. In your case that would look something like this:

```
./redis-trib.rb create 192.168.1.23:6380 192.168.1.29:6382 192.168.1.22:6384
```

Then you can always add the slave manually to a specific master to ensure that each slave is on a different machine than its master. [Adding a new node as a replica](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial#adding-a-new-node-as-a-replica)

```
./redis-trib.rb add-node --slave --master-id <master_id> 192.168.1.22:6385 192.168.1.23:6380
```

Now as far as I know, there is a situation when a slave might be migrated to a get a new master and both end up on the same machine. If you set the `cluster-migration-barrier` to 1 in the redis.conf file, you could have a situation where you have master M1 with slaves S1 & S2 on different machines. You also have master M2 with slave S3 on different machines. If S3 dies and M2 and the slave chosen to migrate over to M2 are on the same machine, then there is no way to automatically avoid the single point of failure.